# pandas.DataFrame input DataFrame but get NaN?

Tags: pandas

df is original DataFrame, csv file.

```
a = df.head(3)                  # get part of df.
```

This is table a.

[image]

```
b = a.loc[1:3,'22':'41']        #select part of a.

c = pd.DataFrame(data=b,index=['a','b'],columns=['v','g']) # give index and columns
```

final

b show 2x2. I get four value.

c show 2x2 NaN. I get four NaN.

why c don't contain any number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `.values`, you are running into 'intrinsic data alignment'

```
c = pd.DataFrame(data=b.values,index=['a','b'],columns=['v','g']) # give index and columns
```

Pandas likes to align indexes, by converting your 'b' dataframe into a np.array, you can then use the pandas dataframe constructor to build a new dataframe with those 2x2 values assigning new indexing.

Answer (score 1):

Your DataFrame `b` already contains row and column indices, so when you try to create DataFrame `c` and you pass `index` and `columns` keyword arguments, you are implicitly indexing out of the original DataFrame `b`.

If all you want to do is re-index `b`, why not do it directly?

```
b = b.copy()
b.index = ['a', 'b']
b.columns = ['v', 'g']
```

Comment: when i tring panda.DataFrame parameters as an exercise, i found this. Then, confused. And i cant understand ?  I just do this step by  step.